# Should I access state from widget or pass it to the state object in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

If I pass some data to a Stateful widget in Flutter, I can in theory access the fields from within the state with `this.widget.state`. However, I've seen some examples passing it further down to the state via a constructor.

Is there a technical reason why to go with one over the other?

Option A:

```
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  String state;
  Page(this.state);
  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}
class _PageState  extends State<Page> {
   // this.widget.state
}
```

Option B:

```
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  String state;
  Page(this.state);
  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState(this.state);
}
class _PageState  extends State<Page> {
  String state;
  _PageState(this.state);
}
```

Comment: the common is `Option A`, see original flutter sources in `widgets` folder

Comment: @pskink Is it just a stylistic preference or is there a reason behind that?

Comment: it is simply much easier - you dont have to duplicate variables and create special state constructors for passing them - check [Image state](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/80b526ea62/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart#L941) for example how it uses `widget`'s data